# longest path in binary tree and return node values

Tags: tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to find the longest path in a binary tree and print out the back. For example:for the tree:
      3 
    /   \ 
   4     5 
        /  \ 
       6    2

I would like to print out either 3,5,6 or 3,5,2.

I have the following code to get the maxdepth which is:

```
public int getMaxDepth(Node<Integer> node){ 
   if (node == null) return 0;
      return 1 + Math.max(node.left, node.right);
}
```

However, after getting the depth I'm not sure how to get the exact path. I was thinking about using a Stack but I'm not sure how to use it. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are using.  There are a couple ways to do this.  I'd do something like:

```
public List<Node<Integer>> getMaxPath(Node<Integer> current, List<Node<Integer>> list){
    if (current == null)
        return list;

    list = list.copy();
    list.append(current);
    List<Node<Integer>> left = getMaxPath(node.left, list);
    List<Node<Integer>> right = getMaxPath(node.right, list);

    return left.length > right.length ? left : right;
} 

getMaxPath(tree.head, new List<Integer>())
```